# Typescript: Access grandparent class method

Tags: typescript

I have a family of three classes:

```
abstract class Form {
    protected async submit({ url: string, data: any }): Promise<void> {
        // submit data from form
    }
}

abstract class BookForm extends Form {
    public name?: string;

    public abstract async submit(): Promise<void>
}

class UpdateBookForm extends BookForm {
    private id: string;

    public async submit(): Promise<void> {
        // Abstract method 'submit' in class 'BookForm' cannot be accessed via super expression.
        return super.submit({
            url: '/book/update',
            data: {
                id: this.id,
                name: this.name,
            }
        });
    }

    constructor(bookId: string) {
        super()
        this.id = bookId;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error when trying to access the `super.submit()` method from `UpdateBookForm`.

> Abstract method 'submit' in class 'BookForm' cannot be accessed via super expression.

What I'm trying to achieve is that `BookForm` is aware of its derivatives containing method `submit()`, without any implementation in `BookForm`.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Maybe I can access the grandparent directly (`super.super`?) from `UpdateBookForm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `abstract` method from `BookForm`, making it:

```
abstract class BookForm extends Form {
    public name?: string;
}
```

Just making `BookForm` `abstract` is sufficient to prevent it being used.

You never want to override a method that exists (in `Form`) with one that doesn't exist (in `BookForm`).

In a comment you've outlined the motivation for making `submit` `abstract` by saying (I've changed "`save`" to "`submit`" in the below to match the question):

> Ok, well say I have an instance of `BookForm` as in `const bookForm = this.book ? new UpdateBookForm(this.book) : new CreateBookForm()` and I attempt to save it `bookForm.submit()` it expects the `submit` method from `Form` which requires arguments. I would want to call `bookForm.submit()`.

If `BookForm` and `UpdateBookForm` don't meaningfully have a `submit` that accepts arguments, then they break the rule that a subclass instance "is a" superclass instance because they aren't `Form`s. There are various ways to solve that. One would be to make `submit` `protected` and have `BookForm` add an `abstract` `save` or something. Then `UpdateBookForm` and `CreateBookForm` would implement `save` by calling `submit`.

But I'd also closely examine whether inheritance is the right call here. It's hard to say without more context.

---

Side note: `BookForm` should probably have a constructor that initializes `name`. Introducing a field without a means of initialzing it at the same level of the hierarchy seems off.

Comment: Ok, well say I have an instance of `BookForm` as in `const bookForm = this.book ? new UpdateBookForm(this.book) : new CreateBookForm()` and I attempt to save it `bookForm.save()` it expects the save method from `Form` which requires arguments. I would want to call `bookForm.save()`.

Comment: @nomadoda - By `save` I assume you mean `submit` (the name used in your question). If `BookForm` and `UpdateBookForm` don't meaningfully have a `submit` that accepts arguments, then they break the rule that a subclass instance "is a" superclass instance because they aren't `Form`s. There are various ways to solve that. One would be to make `submit` private and have `BookForm` add an abstract `save` (not `submit`). Then `UpdateBookForm` and `CreateBookForm` would implement `save` by calling `submit`. But I'd also closely examine whether inheritance is the right call here.

Comment: Thank you so much! I expanded my solution in a separate answer. It seems to make sense in my situation, although I worry I'm digging myself a hole. I'm still trying to learn OOP, and your expertise is very valuable to me. Do you think this way could cause major issues down the line?

Comment: @nomadoda - Nope, should be fine, although again depending on the overall context (which obviously I don't have), the decision to use inheritance for this may or may not be ideal.

Comment: @nomadoda - I've folded the comments above into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You an call it directly using the grandparent class name, although you  might consider redesigning your code.. it has a code smell.

```
abstract class Form {
    async submit({ url: string, data: any }): Promise<void> {
        // submit data from form
    }
}

abstract class BookForm extends Form {
    public name?: string;

    abstract async submit(): Promise<void>
}

class UpdateBookForm extends BookForm {
    private id: string;

    async submit(): Promise<void> {
        return Form.prototype.submit.call(this, {
            url: '/book/update',
            data: {
                id: this.id,
                name: this.name,
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm evaluating some different strategies and, although off-topic, it would be very valuable for me if you could elaborate on the code smell.

Comment: @nomadoda I can't really put in into words, but it seems strange to have method that goes from non abstract to abstract in a derived class. I can't think of a way this could cause a runtime error, but it seems strange to me that is all. That being said, the code above should work, you have the gun to shoot your problem just be careful you don't shoot your foot :P

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to T.J. Crowder's answer, I came to the conclusion that the `Form` `submit({ url: string, data: any })` function's actually quite different from the subclass `submit()` functions, so it makes sense to separate them into two functions as such:

```
abstract class Form {
    protected async submit({ url: string, data: any }): Promise<void> {
        // submit data from form
    }
    public abstract async save(): Promise<void>
}

abstract class BookForm extends Form {
    public name?: string;

    public abstract async save(): Promise<void>
}

class UpdateBookForm extends BookForm {
    private id: string;

    public async save(): Promise<void> {
        return super.submit({
            url: '/book/update',
            data: {
                id: this.id,
                name: this.name,
            }
        });
    }

    constructor(bookId: string) {
        super()
        this.id = bookId;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to redeclare `save` in `BookForm`. It inherits it from `Form`.